# Javascript confirm before running the eventhandler, which deletes records from the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, button, onclick

I have button, which fires an event, that deletes a record from the database. This is the source of the button:

`<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete"                   onclick="btnDelete_Click" />`

But how can I make a confirm box appear before the deletion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the button's OnClientClick property:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" OnClientClick="confirmDelete" ... >

<script type="text/javascript">
function confirmDelete()
{
  return confirm('Really delete this record?');
}
</script>
```